# Task not returning IsCompleted state

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

Following code has a bug: `result` doesn't contain any state; `IsCompleted`, `IsCanceled` and `IsFaulted` are always false, but I tested that `Task` works correctly, where is a problem?

```
var result = _dataService.SyncPoll(webApiPoll); 

if (result.IsCompleted)
{
    _logger.Info("Execute sync, poll was completed");
    poll.IsSynchronized = true;
    poll.ServerStatus = ServerStatus.Active;
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}

//////

public Task SyncPoll(PollDto poll)
{
    if (!_isAuthorized)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var client = new ApiClient(_baseApiUrl, _authToken);
    Task result = Task.Run(async () => await client.SyncPollWeb(poll));
    return result;
}

///////

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SyncPollWeb(PollDto poll)
{
    HttpResponseMessage resp;
    //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
    using (var client = GetClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(_authType, _accessToken);
        resp = await client.PostAsJsonAsync<PollDto>("api/poll", poll);
    }
    return resp;
}
```

Comment: Did you wait for the task to complete before you checked those states? From your code, I can't see that. And while the task is running, all those three states are of course `false`.

Comment: You need to await the task returned by result.  It will complete *asynchronously*, so it will almost never be completed by the time you check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you are doing actually is a `fire and forget` so you don't have the status with such principle

The issue come from the [`await`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx)
you have to add await in order to have back the status

```
  var result =  await _dataService.SyncPoll(webApiPoll);
```

//and here

```
 Task result = await   client.SyncPollWeb(poll);
```

Comment: This is the correct way await the asynchronous Task or may even use Task.WhenAll an then await in the calling layer

Comment: oh now i see,thanks=)but something missed in this solution,somewher we should change method return type

Answer (score 0):

That's happened because when you checking the state your task is not finished (and running) yet - you just create it. You should wait until any state is deternined for your task. Use

```
result.Wait();
```

before checking for result.IsCompleted

Comment: In WebApi Wait / WaitAll will lead to deadlock, you need WhenAll or simple await, check http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: thank you, it seems like an easiest way to shoot yourself in C#